# Regular Expression to Match 2nd and 5th character

Tags: regex, replace, insert

i am looking for a regular expression to match the 2nd and 5th character of a string at once.
I want to use it to insert a start behind these positions.

Already got it working by selecting a single character by using `^(.{2})` but didn't get it to work also selecting the 5th character.

I hope you can help me and thanks in advance :)

Comment: "I want to use it to insert a start" What's a "start"? Can you show some sample inputs and outputs? Also, what language/tool are you using?

Comment: What language are you using? Why don't you directly access them by index? (i.e `string[2]`, `string[5]`)